# Selectbox issue

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have an issue with my code below. I populated my selectbox from my db which works fine. But when I select an option it wont send the value to my other php file I am relative new to jQuery so I hope that I have a small error in my code I hope that someone can help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        var dropd = $("#drop").val();
        $.getJSON('data.php?id='+dropd)
```

So when I press button1 it should put the value from my selectbox in the variable dropd and send it to the php site data.php right?

So this is the code for my select box which should be alright.

```
   <select id ="drop">
  <option disabled selected>--Wähle Station aus--</option>
  <?php
    $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT idStation, Stationname FROM station WHERE fi_idFirma = $id");
      while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
       {
         echo "<option value='".$data['idStation']."'>" .$data['Stationname']."</option>";
       }
  ?>
</select>
```

My problem is I think that i want several codes to start at once in jquery because when i press button1 it loads the value from dropd to data.php and than it should load an json file where i populate my graphs with.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    var dropd = $("#drop").val();
    $.getJSON('data.php?id='+dropd)
      function grab() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                resolve(data)
            },
            error: function(error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        })
    })
}

    grab().then((data) => {
        console.log('Recieved our data', data);
        let Zeit = [];
        let Luft = [];

        try {
            data.forEach((item) => {
                Zeit.push(item.Zeit)
                Luft.push(item.Luftfeuchtigkeit)
            });

            let chartdata1 = {
                labels: [...Zeit],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Luftfeuchtigkeit',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: [...Luft]
                }]
            };

            let ctx = $("#myChart1");

            let barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata1
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error parsing JSON data', error)
        }

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

I know it looks a bit messy but i hope that you can help me in this case.

This is the data.php file where the select value should arrive.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","usera01");
$id = isset($_GET['dropd']) ? $_GET['dropd'] : false;
   if ($id) {
      echo ($_GET['dropd']);
   } else {
     $id = 1;
   }

$sqlQuery = "SELECT idDatenNr, Luftfeuchtigkeit, Lichtverhältnis, Bodenfeuchtigkeit,Temperatur, Zeit, fi_idStation FROM daten WHERE fi_idStation = '$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQuery);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
 $data[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($conn);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Maybe i made here an mistake.

Comment: The logic of your jquery seems correct, but we need to see the html for the select in order to tell you if everything is okay. Also consider using a `console.log(dropd)` before your `getJSON`, that way you can test if the value is correct or not.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't send anything to the back end? Btw, would rather write the get request as: `$.getJSON('data.php', {id: dropd});` so that jQuery can encode the values properly. If you put it in the URL like you are, you might need to url encode the value, depending on what it is. You can also pass a success function as the third argument where you can log what you get back.

Comment: In the Browser press F12 and a really useful "Developer Tools" windows will open. There is a JS debugger in there as well as lots of other useful tools

Comment: What does `resolve(data)` do ? PS Missing `;` on that line

Comment: i used the console.log and the value is correct so i dont know why i cant send it to my data.php file.

Comment: I ve posted also the code from my data.php file maybe i screwed up there something

Comment: I believe the first echo the php file (on drops) is interfering. Comment that out and try another run.